# Write JS var into html header script source

Tags: javascript, variables, html-head

putting a var into the html isn't that difficult and I found many examples. But it seems I have a special task...

At the beginning of an html file I define a js var with a name of a javascript file. 
Further down I load all the other JS files by this:

```
<script src="jss/blah.js"></script>
```

What I need is to put the content of a js var into this line like this:

```
<script src="jss/#here-comes-my-JS-var#.js"></script>
```

I tried several ways without success. Is that not possible?

Comment: Of course this is a duplicate! But of what question? How to find that question? Millions of tipps of how to put a var into the html. But hard to find what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var yourVars = 'somePathOrWhatever';
var scriptToInclude = document.createElement('script');
scriptToInclude.setAttribute('src','jss/' + yourVars + '.js');
document.head.appendChild(scriptToInclude);
```

Comment: hmm... it works, but I think there is an issue with the time of loading the js file. somitmes it works, sometimes not...

Comment: In case ypu realy can't avoid using this hacks, you may want to include that part of your code that depends on this 'jss/' + yourVars + '.js' file into javascript self invoking function (function() {// your code ... })(); and place it to the bottom of your page and after executing script from answer. So the code inside will be executed after DOM will fully loaded and after var script will be included into it.